# What makes artificial intelligence artificial?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, artificial-intelligence, intelligence

Wikipedia says `Artificial intelligence (AI) is intelligence exhibited by machines.` About intelligence it says `It [intelligence] can be more generally described as the ability to perceive information, and retain it as knowledge to be applied towards adaptive behaviors within an environment or context.`

I was thinking, if machines are able to perform this tasks and thinks for itself, what makes this intelligence artificial?

Comment: It is 'artificial' in that it would be an 'artifice' -- something purposely constructed.  We/dolphins/signing apes are not constructed for the purpose of being intelligent, we grow in a natural environment.

Comment: Isn't it that we give the machine the ability to be intelligent, but that it gains intelligence itself by learning?

Comment: If the metaphor here is to mean anything, parallelism needs to be maintained: intelligence has to be what makes learning possible, rather than knowledge, which is the result of learning.  Someone can be highly intelligent, and be a young child, so that they learn very well but have not yet learned much, or even have something like rolling amnesia, so that they can think very well but learn very little.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: We are still a long way from defining intelligence, and that is the real challenge. 
If we could accurately define it, then it would be easy to reverse engineer it and create artificial intelligence that matches "natural" intelligence (artificial coming from the fact that it is created by humans and not found naturally).

I work in artificial intelligence research and in my experience the best performing systems (showing general intelligence and not task specific performance) are the ones that learn based on a **naive** interpretation of neurons and neural networks in the brain. 
The world is just too complicated to model or to hard code a reactive system to give it the feel of intelligence, so we use non-parametric models that try to estimate a representation of the world given the data streams available

Answer (score -1):

I believe the simple answer would be that this intelligence is not naturally occurring, but engineered or created.

Once created it learns naturally, but there is still the prerequisite of being created.